# $ \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+x^{2^{n-1}})=\dfrac{1}{1-x}\quad (|x|<1) $

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, infinite-product

Prove that:
$$
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+x^{2^{n-1}})=\dfrac{1}{1-x}\quad (|x|<1)
$$

My answer is like this:
$$
\dfrac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\cdots\\=(1+x)+(x^2+x^3)+\cdots\\=(1+x)(1+x^2+\cdots)\\=(1+x)((1+x^2)+(x^4+x^6)+\cdots)\\=(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4+\cdots)\\=\cdots=LHS
$$
Is my solution correct and rigorous, if not, how to solve the problem? Thanks!

Comment: But you are not providing any reason to pass from the first line to the second or 3rd line. Add why is that the case.

Comment: I have editted my solution. Would you bother to check it again? Is it correct to do something like that to infinite products?

Comment: Use $$(1-y)(1+y)=1-y^2$$  for $y=x,x^2,x^4,\cdots$

Comment: You could rephrase your argument as $$\frac1{1-x}=(1+x)\frac1{1-x^2}
=(1+x)(1+x^2)\frac1{1-x^4}=\cdots.$$